# Get url from href using AngleSharp library

Tags: c#, .net, anglesharp

I'm using c# with AngleSharp library to read URL from `<a>` 
I can read content easily using

```
var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("a");
```

But what shall I do, to read URL from `href` attribute in all `<a>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this :**

```
var anchors = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").OfType<IHtmlAnchorElement>();
foreach (var a in anchors)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.Text); // prints the link inner text
    Console.WriteLine("Href = " + GetAttribute("href")); // prints all the links
}
// if you are using winforms then replace console.writeline with string text
```